# Weird issue in encapsulated coroutines in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, coroutine

I have a weird problem, that i don't really understand.
Basically i have 3 Classes : A, B and C. Class A and C are attached to a GameObject, Class B not.

Class A:

```
public class A : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public void Foo() 
    {
        string text = "some text here";
        StartCoroutine(B.Bar(text));
    }
}
```

Class B:

```
public class B : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public IEnumerator Bar(string text) 
    {
        // do some stuff
        yield return Something(text);
    }

    public IEnumerator Something(string text) 
    {
        // do some stuff
        yield return C.FooBar(new List<string>(text.Split(someChar)));
        // wait for C.FooBar and do some more stuff
    }    
}
```

Class C:

```
public class C : MonoBehaviour
{
    public IEnumerator FooBar(List<string> names) 
    {
        while (names.Length > 0)
        {
            // do some stuff
            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
            names.RemovaAt(0);
        }

    } 
}
```

The problem is, that B.Something(string text) stops on every yield return (there are some other yield returns in that function, where i must wait for something). But all this worked yesterday after a tons of testing and i don't know, what i am doing wrong and why this suddenly not working.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "stops"? Leaving out all of the returns in your function makes this a guessing game.

Comment: The function FooBar in C is searching for a GameObject in the scene with the name of the first entry on the list, then the first entry will be removed. in the next turn i am searching for a child named like the first entry on the list and remove it and so on. If the while Loop is done the function returns the last found GameObject and B.Something() must wait for it. With "stops" i mean, the code after the yield return won't be executed. But this Code already worked yesterday.

Comment: There is no way that code can compile. You can't access non static functions like this add using a code that's now what is on your side makes it harder to help you

Comment: Yes, i know. This is not the real code, it should be just a short example. My main question is, what can cause, that a coroutine which already worked, on the next day just not returning (without any changes in the code)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that the first object was destroyed before the other class' coroutine ended. I still don't get, why it is already worked yesterday, but now i'm waiting for the coroutine and destroy the gameobject after it ends and it works fine now.